# how to write an empty column in a csv based on other columns in the same csv file

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, conditional-statements

I don't know whether this is a very simple qustion, but I would like to do a condition statement based on two other columns.
I have two columns like: the age and the SES and the another empty column which should be based on these two columns. For example when one person is 65 years old  and its corresponding socio-economic status is high, then in the third column(empty column=vitality class) a value of *1* is for example given. I have got an idea about what I want to achieve, however I have no idea how to implement that in python itself. I know I should use a *for* loop and I know how to write conditons, however due to the fact that I want to take two columns into consideration for determining what will be written in the empty column, I have no idea how to write that in a function
and furthermore how to write back  into the same csv (in the respective empty column)

[[image]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the pandas module to import the csv as a DataFrame object. Then you can do logical statements to fill empty columns:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('path_to_file.csv')
df.loc[(df['age']==65) & (df['SES']=='high'), 'vitality_class'] = 1
df.to_csv('path_to_new_file.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: I managed to install pandas en use your code in a function, however when I try to run the code, the vitality_class column remains empty. :(

Comment: Is the age column stored as an integer or as a string? If it is a string, then you need to add quotes to the 65. Also, is it giving you an error about assigning a value to a slice? I'll edit it so that it uses the proper .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value strategy

Comment: hi mathisfun, when I adjust the code with df.loc[(df['age'] >65)& (df['age'] <75) & (df['SES'] == 'high') ,'vital'] = '1', then it did work. Thank for the suggestion

Comment: @Joy I'm glad you got it worked out. Feel free to accept the answer so that future readers can quickly see that.